# simple regex for popping out the string

Tags: regex

I have following strings.

```
<b>as early</b> and <b>as many</b>
```

here I wanna pop it out the string "as early and as many"

I tried like this.

^/w+ /w+$

but it doesn't give me the result. what regex should I insert?

of course for that example, if I  insert "as early" for the regex
it will give me the result. but what I want is 
how can I pop out the string between  **and**  tag

Comment: What kind of language you are using?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that will of course only select the bits that are between the tags

Answer (score 0):

the regex: `/(.*?)<\/?b>/g`

the replace string: `$1`

output: `"as early and as many"`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW0tI3/1)